# Python pandas getting value of the dictionary in column

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas to create a dataframe and it is all fine, but i have two columns, which have dictionaries in it. How to split this columns to extract price value and stake value.

```
             AgainstSidePrices                        ForSidePrices
0    {u'_Price': 4.8, u'_Stake': 160.69}   {u'_Price': 4.6, u'_Stake': 21.44}   
1      {u'_Price': 4.8, u'_Stake': 5.69}     {u'_Price': 4.7, u'_Stake': 4.0}   
2     {u'_Price': 5.0, u'_Stake': 22.32}   {u'_Price': 4.9, u'_Stake': 15.34}   
3     {u'_Price': 5.6, u'_Stake': 15.18}   {u'_Price': 5.4, u'_Stake': 14.82}   
4      {u'_Price': 9.6, u'_Stake': 4.22}    {u'_Price': 9.4, u'_Stake': 6.71}   
5      {u'_Price': 12.5, u'_Stake': 4.0}  {u'_Price': 11.5, u'_Stake': 12.35}   
6     {u'_Price': 950.0, u'_Stake': 2.0}  {u'_Price': 128.0, u'_Stake': 2.25}   
7                                    NaN                                  NaN   
8      {u'_Price': 4.8, u'_Stake': 4.72}    {u'_Price': 4.6, u'_Stake': 9.32}   
9       {u'_Price': 4.9, u'_Stake': 2.0}    {u'_Price': 4.7, u'_Stake': 3.92}
```

I have a solution for this, but the problem appears when there is NaN like line 7.

```
table['price'] = table['AgainstSidePrices'].apply(lambda x: x.get('_Price'))
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: so are you just wanting to ignore the `NaN`? `table.loc[table['AgainstSidePrices'].notnull(), 'AgainstSidePrices'].apply(lambda x: x.get('_Price'))`

Comment: Thanks. It all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, either apply it to the non-null entries:

```
table.AgainstSidePrices[table.AgainstSideProces.notnull()].apply(...)
```

or change the `apply` function to handle this:

```
... apply(lambda x: <something> if x is None else x.get('_Price'))
```

Note that the dimensions of the answers are different: the first applies it only to the relevant rows, the second to all.